# JPA @Embeddable

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using @ElementCollection for a custom object list

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "choice", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "itemId"))
@OrderColumn(name = "index")
private List<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<Choice>();
```

I have created a Choice class like this

```
//@Embeddable
@Table(name = "choice")
@Cacheable(false)
@Audited
public class Choice implements Serializable{
```

If I use @Embeddable annotation I am getting `org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported for auditing: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType`

I am new to JPA. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: What don't you understand? The message is pretty clear: you can't audit a component/embeddable. Make it a real entity.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `@Embeddable`, the field that refers to the `@Embeddable` class needs to have the `@Embedded` annotation. Then, the fields in the `@Embedded` class need to have proper JPA annotations so JPA knows what to do with them. You may want to read [this](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Embeddable) in order to fully understand what `@Embbedable` does.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I wasn't aware I can do the formatting by using a back quote.